# Generating random unique 3D binary matrices

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, random, binary

I created a list containing a thousand random 10*10*10 binary matrices.

```
P=[]
for idx in range (0,1000):
    s=(10,10,10)
    a=np.zeros(s)
    for i in range (0,10):
        for j in range (0,10):
            for k in range (0,10):
                c=np.random.random(1)
                if c>0.5:
                    c=1
                else:
                    c=0
                a[i][j][k]=c
    P.append(a)
```

After that, I tried the following to make sure none of the matricies are repeated. However, I get an error for that.

```
unique_set=[]
for idx in P:
    if idx not in unique_set:
        unique_set.append(idx)
unique_set
```

This is the error I get:

**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

What should I try instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because the truthiness of the array needs to be evaluated internally when `if idx not in unique_set` is executed.

The solution depends on your intent. If you consider two arrays equal if all their elements are equal, then you can do this:

```
for idx in P:
    if not any(np.array_equal(idx, other_idx) for other_idx in unique_set):
        unique_set.append(idx)
```

This compares each `idx` with all the previous `idx`es present in `unique_set`. The element-wise comparison is handled within `np.array_equals`.

Aside from your error, you really should consider using `np.random.choice` to generate your `P`. This will be significantly faster than `for` loops in pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to compare with `np.array_equal` for every array in `unique_set`.

```
def is_unique(array, unique_arrays):
    for arr in unique_arrays:
        if np.array_equal(array, arr):
            return False
    return True
```

This function will return if the array is unique or not. Your code will look like:

```
unique_set=[]
for idx in P:
    if is_unique(idx, unique_set):
      unique_set.append(idx)
unique_set
```